# A check list method of identifying combination vs permutation

Tags: probability, combinatorics

**Problem: What is the possible combinations of selecting four balls out of a bag of six Red, four White, five Green balls.**

This is a simple combinatorics question. The question is incredibly easy but I am using it as a case study to understand the **step-by-step**  mechanics of solving much more complicated combinatorics question.

I am trying to identify when and when to use combination vs permutation. How can I identify? Is there a test? Here is my attempt:

I first number the balls in the bag.

**Red**: $R_1, R_2, R_3, R_4, R_5, R_6$

**White**: $W_1, W_2, W_3, W_4$

**Green**: $G_1, G_2, G_3, G_4, G_5$

I like to use a slots method. I number the slots as each ball selected from the bag.

I consider a simple, possible outcome that is in the outcome space.

$\{ \text{Slot Combo 1} \} = \frac{ \quad R_2 \quad   }{1} \frac{ \quad G_1 \quad   }{2} \frac{ \quad W_1 \quad   }{3} \frac{ \quad R_1 \quad   }{4} $

To figure out whether I need to use combination or permutation I ask two questions:

**Question 1:** If I reorder my example combo, is the new combination still in the possible outcome space I am considering?

$\{ \text{Slot Combo 2} \} = \frac{ \quad  G_1 \quad   }{1} \frac{ \quad   R_1\quad   }{2} \frac{ \quad  R_2 \quad   }{3} \frac{ \quad W_1 \quad   }{4} $

The answer is yes! Order does not matter.

**Question 2:** If I redraw my example combo but from the same subsets and cannot distinguish the numbering of the balls, is the new outcome in the outcome space?

$\{ \text{Slot Combo 3} \} = \frac{ \quad R_3 \quad   }{1} \frac{ \quad G_1 \quad   }{2} \frac{ \quad W_1 \quad   }{3} \frac{ \quad R_5 \quad   }{4}  $

The answer is yes! Whether I draw $\{ R_1 , R_2 \}$ or $\{ R_3,R_5 \}$, the uniqueness of the ball does not matter only the fact I drew two red balls matters.

My query to you: Of these two questions **Q1** and **Q2** which tells me (identifies) that I have to use combination $ {n \choose k}$ ? Is it both?

Question 2 comes from that fact that even though in combinations we assume each element in a subset is distinct (we number the red balls, white balls and green) making each element unique, when we consider arrangements we assume distinct elements in a subset are indistinguishable. I.e. it does not matter if you drew $R_2$ or $R_5$, only thing that matters is that you drew a red ball.

Comment: You distinguish the balls by color  only since you cannot distinguish balls of the same color.

Comment: I would say Q1 as we can clearly see that **any** arrangement of the exact same balls yields nothing different

Comment: I hear you all your presented is Red, White and Green balls and balls of the same color are not distinct. But in combination you make them distinct. So is **Q2** not useful in identifying combination vs permutation?

Comment: Even if the items are not distinct we assume they are distinct in combination. But isn't combination the arranging of distinct items?

Comment: As per my knowledge (which might be incorrect) **combination** is just the number of ways in which we can pick $r$ items out of $n$ but **permutation** on the other hand is the number of ways we can arrange the $r$ items that we picked

Comment: Your example in Question $2$ leaves something to be desired, because you have re-ordered the colors.  Suppose the redraw is $R_3,G_1,W_1,R_5$  If you say it's the same, I don't know if order matters or not.  Question $1$ is the one to go with.

Comment: Does Q2 always imply Q1? Note that I redrew the sample. I grabbed different balls but of the same colors. Q1 the same exact balls were reconsidered but only in a different ordering.

Comment: All i am trying to do with my post is find a simple, comprehensive, litmus question, that even a 5 year old child could ask, that would identify combination the use of the combination formula ${n \choose k}$.

Comment: You cannot distinguish between balls of the same color. Thus you are looking for the number of $\textrm{combinations}$. It is a bit misleading that you distinguish between balls of the same color.

Comment: Okay. Consider the probability of drawing two Aces out of a deck of 52, if two cards are drawn. The answer is $\frac{{4 \choose 2} }{{52 \choose 2} }$ . In this example, I can distingiush what type of Ace I have (Ace of clubs, Ace of Diamonds, Ace of Hearts, Ace of Spades). But I still use combination.

Comment: You can but you must not. The question refers to aces in general. So use combination. You have two kinds of cards: *non-aces* and *aces*. This is the criteria for distinguishing here.